# spinner if item selected again

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I created a class file in my package, called NoDefaultSpinner. When I try to use it in my Android app, though, I get an exception that crashes the program.

I copied the code provided by Dimitar Vukman and Blundell from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335306/how-can-i-get-an-event-in-android-spinner-when-the-current-selected-item-is-sele) and then updated this code as Alex Miragall instructed some posts down (because now I'm creating an application for Android 4.0). I removed Dimitar's onClick method and pasted Alex's code at the end of the class.

Then I edited my activity with spinners, I changed

```
static Spinner spinner1;
```

to

```
static NoDefaultSpinner spinner1;
```

and

```
variables.spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

to

```
variables.spinner1 = (NoDefaultSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

Also I tried to change

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/place" />
```

to

```
<NoDefaultSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/place" />
```

The question: what I did wrong, why my app crashes and what can I do to make it work properly?

These are the errors if i don't update layout:

```
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.life/com.example.life.search_activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to com.example.life.NoDefaultSpinner
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to com.example.life.NoDefaultSpinner
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at com.example.life.search_activity.onCreate(search_activity.java:181)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-08 01:50:48.835: E/AndroidRuntime(13362):    ... 11 more
```

These are errors if I do update the layout (change Spinner to NoDefaultSpinner)

```
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.life/com.example.life.search_activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class NoDefaultSpinner
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class NoDefaultSpinner
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at com.example.life.search_activity.onCreate(search_activity.java:177)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    ... 11 more
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.NoDefaultSpinner" on path: /data/app/com.example.life-1.apk
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-08 01:53:22.803: E/AndroidRuntime(13417):    ... 21 more
```

I have found two solutions for my problem here on stack:

[The first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335306/how-can-i-get-an-event-in-android-spinner-when-the-current-selected-item-is-sele)

[The second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937150/android-spinner-fire-event-when-same-item-selection-is-made?rq=1)

I have the same problem that had people who asked these questions. The problem is well presented there.

I tried all the solutions, but every time I tried to launch an activity with these special spinners application crashed. Maybe I did use the classes wrong?

Comment: You might need to do `<com.mypackage.NoDefaultSpinner` (So use the full name of the Class). Also, post your LogCat, so everyone can see exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I call this class from the same package, there is no need to use the full name. I'll write logs in a few minutes

Comment: Yes there is, when you're using it in XML. As @A--C says, use the fully qualified package name when referencing your custom View in XML.

Comment: This is because when you're writing XML for Android apps, the parser always assumes that the default namespace for XML tags is somewhere in `android`. In your Java, code, though, you're right, you don't need fully qualified names for things in the same package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first exception is caused by

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.NoDefaultSpinner" on path: /data/app/com.example.life-1.apk
```

So use the fully qualified name (`com.myPackage.NoDefaultSpinner`) in your xml layout. Otherwise, Android assumes the class is part of its own package and it will obviously fail.

Also, this:

```
ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to com.example.life.NoDefaultSpinner
```

Suggests that `NoDefaultSpinner` does not extend `Spinner`, make sure it is.

Comment: ok, great, I've changed <NoDefaultSpinner in my xml with <com.example.life.NoDefaultSpinner, now it works, but with one exeption, reacts only after the second click on the element already selected. If I click on an element that is not selected already everithing is fine.
Maybe it is so because I use a counter to check if the element selected by user or not, like so:
`i=0;
    ...
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
       int position, long id) { 
    CharSequence t2 = (CharSequence) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    if(i>0){ 
   ...
   } if(i==0) i++;`