# ActionBar onNavigationItemSelected not called when selected item remains the same

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I am using the ActionBar drop-down navigation with OnNavigationListener implemented.
The requirement is to fire the onNavigationItemSelected() method every time, also when the same drop-down item is selected. The default Android implementation prevents the onNavigationItemSelected() method from running when the same item is selected.

I have seen the solutions to this requirement only for the standard Spinner implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937150/android-spinner-fire-event-when-same-item-selection-is-made) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854329/spinner-onitemselected-not-called-when-selected-item-remains-the-same/11227847#11227847), however not for the specific ActionBar drop-down navigation implementation.

Any suggestions how to overcome this default Android behaviour would be most appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    mPosition = -1; 
    actionBar = getActionBar();  
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    ....
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.eventmenu, menu);

    SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(actionBar.getThemedContext(), R.array.s_events,
              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);                 
    OnNavigationListener mOnNavigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {                       

          @Override
          public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {

              if (mPosition > -1) {     // to prevent opening the data entry fragment when the Events fragment is initially opened


                ...
                  startActivity(newEvent);                    
              }
              mPosition = position;
              return true;                            
          }       

    };                  
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mOnNavigationListener);    
    return true;
}
```