# How to add inherited class to XML layout in android

Tags: android

I am following this link : 
[android spinner fire event when same item selection is made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937150/android-spinner-fire-event-when-same-item-selection-is-made)

I extended `Spinner` class as mentioned in the link. Below is my code:

```
    public class SpinnerTrigger extends Spinner {

    public SpinnerTrigger(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
public void setSelection(int position, boolean animate) {
    ignoreOldSelectionByReflection();
    super.setSelection(position, animate);
}

private void ignoreOldSelectionByReflection() {
        try {
        Class<?> c = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass();
        Field reqField = c.getDeclaredField("mOldSelectedPosition");
        reqField.setAccessible(true);
        reqField.setInt(this, -1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception Private", "ex", e);
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    ignoreOldSelectionByReflection();
    super.setSelection(position);
}

}
```

I added the above class in my layout file with fully qualified name:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.mypack.cc.SpinnerTrigger
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/options"
        android:prompt="@string/text_prompt" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

When I am trying run my application, I am getting error logs as mentioned below:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12:Error inflating class com.mypack.cc.SpinnerTrigger
```

Please suggest me If I miss something here.

Comment: Please include the whole stack trace of the error

Answer (score 0):

ASdd this to your layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:tag="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mypack.cc"  <!--   HERE -->
```